# Hide default initializer argument name

Tags: swift

Let's say I have a struct 'A' that looks as follows:

```
struct A {
    var value: Int

    init(_ value: Int) {
       self.value = value
    }
}
```

And my question is - is there any way to hide value name without using custom initializer? I want to achieve something like this:

```
struct A {
    @HideArgumentNamePropertyWrapper var value: Int
}
```

And call should looks like this:

```
let a = A(1) // yes
// instead of: let a = A(value: 1)
```

Comment: You say you dont wanna write custom initializer yet in your question you have added a custom `init` which basically helps you to achieve what you want `A(1)` are you trying to say you dont wanna write that custom `init` ? Yet achieve this `A(1)` effect? By Default swift provides a paramertized constructor to struct if you havent provided your own designated `init` So I dont think you can get away without writing custom init

Comment: No it is not possible.